# Auto increment field of model in viewset during saving

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Episode model has episode_number field, which has to be auto incremented while creating new episode. Every story will have episodes with episode_number field starting with one. How to do that? Now I user have to manually enter episode_number. story_id comes from url

```
class Story(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location)
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre)
    author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Episode(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location)
    story = models.ForeignKey(Story, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    episode_number = models.IntegerField(null=True)

class EpisodeView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = EpisodeSerializer
    permission_classes = [BasicAuthorizationPermissions]

    def get_queryset(self):
        story_id = self.kwargs['story_id']
        return Episode.objects.filter(story=story_id)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        try:
            story = Story.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['story_id'])
        except Story.DoesNotExist:
            raise NotFound

        if self.request.user != story.author:
            raise PermissionDenied

        return serializer.save(story=story)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Case scenario

When there is a new entry in `Episod` model based on reference `Story` model `episode_number` should automatically populate.

#### Possible solution

We are going to overwrite `Episod` model's default save method and check if this is an entry for new instance we will set its value from here.

```
class Episode(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location)
    story = models.ForeignKey(Story, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    episode_number = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk: # new instance
            self.episode_number = Episode.objects.filter(story=self.story).count() + 1

        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: the point is that, if  there are 30 episodes in db, and i am creating new story and want to create episode of the story, pk will be 31, but episode_number must be 1.
In your case it will store only 31

Comment: can you please post your `story` model too. And how you manage the relation between story and Episode model.

Comment: posted, only foreign key and EpisodeSerializer contains StorySerializer for story field

Comment: @DanabekDuisekov i am afraid without overwriting `model` save method this not possible. Your approaches is also one of the solution. But better to do that in `method-save` because it will serve as single source of operation. Which is very important. If you want i can update my answer.

Comment: sure, i will try